# Onclick confirmation and then redirect

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am trying to confirm then redirect to new page.

if I delete `return` before `confirm` it confirms either way but if I keep `return` it does not redirect to link.

```
<button name="payment" class="btn btn-xs-6 btn-danger btn-block" type="button"
    onclick="return confirm('are you sure you want to cancel?');window.location.href='cancel';"
    value="fav_HTML">Cancel Payment
</button>
```

Comment: lol why this question is down voted? I don't see anything against stackoverflow rules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the value of `confirm()`, which indicates if the user confirmed or cancelled. So, instead of

```
return confirm('are you sure you want to cancel?'); window.location.href='cancel';
```

you should do

```
if (confirm('are you sure you want to cancel?')) window.location.href='cancel';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r = confirm('are you sure you want to cancel?');
if (r == true) {
    window.location.href='cancel';
} else {
   //
}
```

Comment: `confirm()` only returns boolean values, so `if (r == true)` can be replaced with `if (r)`.

Comment: @LostMyGlasses, sure